# Servant: upload file as multipart/form-data

Tags: haskell, servant

What is the way to implement a file upload API with `Servant`?
I am trying to handle "standard" `multipart/form-data` but cannot figure out how to declare it in Servant.

This obviously doesn't work as it cannot handle multiparts:

```
type API = "file" :> ReqBody '[OctetStream] ByteString :> Post '[OctetStream] ()
```

Does Servant support file uploads?

Comment: I prefer upload resources using ajax but if you want forms, read https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/133

Comment: Can you advice on the differences? I thought supporting multiparts was more "standard" way of doing it plus it will allow faster uploads due to parallelism

Comment: "I prefer" why I prefer expose my services as client API (and you can upload many files at a time, has more fine grained control over each request, ...). Using (e.g) FORM is more cheap but much more coupled (ui <-> ws).

Answer (score 1):

This combinator works well. Just put it in a file in your app.  https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/133#issuecomment-125235662